# How do I concatenate the values of a column in a window every 6th row, separated by a space?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have been having issues trying to archieve my goal of concatenating values (with a space) in a window of 6 rows if possible.

I'm currently using Azure Databricks with Pyspark 3.4.1, and this is the data I am currently using:

```
data = [
    ("1000","999", "1", "123", "123 abc 456 def 789 ghi 101112 jkl 131415"),
    ("1000","999", "2", "abc", "123 abc 456 def 789 ghi 101112 jkl 131415"),
    ("1000","999", "3", "456", "123 abc 456 def 789 ghi 101112 jkl 131415"),
    ("1000","999", "4", "def", "123 abc 456 def 789 ghi 101112 jkl 131415"),
    ("1000","999", "5", "789", "123 abc 456 def 789 ghi 101112 jkl 131415"),
    ("1000","999", "6", "ghi", "123 abc 456 def 789 ghi 101112 jkl 131415"),
    ("1000","999", "7", "101112", "101112 jkl 131415"),
    ("1000","999", "8", "jkl", "101112 jkl 131415"),
    ("1000","999", "9", "131415", "101112 jkl 131415"),
    ("1001","999", "1", "aaa", "aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff"),
    ("1001","999", "2", "bbb", "aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff"),
    ("1001","999", "3", "ccc", "aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff"),
    ("1001","999", "4", "ddd", "aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff"),
    ("1001","999", "5", "eee", "aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff"),
    ("1001","999", "6", "fff", "aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff"),
    ("1002","999", "1", "data", "data"),
    ("1003","900", "1", "stack", "stack over flow .com"),
    ("1003","900", "2", "over", "stack over flow .com"),
    ("1003","900", "3", "flow", "stack over flow .com"),
    ("1003","900", "4", ".com", "stack over flow .com"),
    ("1003","997", "1", "py", "py spark databricks"),
    ("1003","997", "2", "spark", "py spark databricks"),
    ("1003","997", "3", "databricks", "py spark databricks"),
    ("1003","998", "1", "data science", "data science data engineering"),
    ("1003","998", "2", "data engineering", "data science data engineering"),
    ("1003","999", "1", "azure", "azure aws gcp"),
    ("1003","999", "2", "aws", "azure aws gcp"),
    ("1003","999", "3", "gcp", "azure aws gcp")
]
```

I was hoping the output would look like the 4th column.

I have tried using multiple windows and group functions like the following:

```
window_spec = Window().partitionBy("col1").orderBy("col3").rowsBetween(Window.currentRow - 5, Window.currentRow)

df = df.withColumn("col5", when(col("col3") == 6, concat_ws(" ", collect_list("col2").over(window_spec))))
```

But my technical skills are not enough to achieve my result.

In which way can I achieve the desired output? Which functions should I use? Is this possible to solve using SparkSQL?

Comment: please provide a sample input and the output that you would like to get

Answer (score 0):

you could create a grouping column using the 3rd column, and then use `collect_list`.

here's an example *(the first six rows of the last column in your example looks incorrect if you want to group sequence of 6 rows)*

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('grp_flg', func.ceil(func.col('c3') / 6)). \
    withColumn('concatstr', 
               func.concat_ws(' ', 
                              func.collect_list('c4').
                              over(wd.partitionBy('c1', 'c2', 'grp_flg').orderBy('c3').rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize))
                              )
               ). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +----+---+---+------+-----------------------------------------+-------+-----------------------+
# |c1  |c2 |c3 |c4    |c5                                       |grp_flg|concatstr              |
# +----+---+---+------+-----------------------------------------+-------+-----------------------+
# |1000|999|1  |123   |123 abc 456 def 789 ghi 101112 jkl 131415|1      |123 abc 456 def 789 ghi|
# |1000|999|2  |abc   |123 abc 456 def 789 ghi 101112 jkl 131415|1      |123 abc 456 def 789 ghi|
# |1000|999|3  |456   |123 abc 456 def 789 ghi 101112 jkl 131415|1      |123 abc 456 def 789 ghi|
# |1000|999|4  |def   |123 abc 456 def 789 ghi 101112 jkl 131415|1      |123 abc 456 def 789 ghi|
# |1000|999|5  |789   |123 abc 456 def 789 ghi 101112 jkl 131415|1      |123 abc 456 def 789 ghi|
# |1000|999|6  |ghi   |123 abc 456 def 789 ghi 101112 jkl 131415|1      |123 abc 456 def 789 ghi|
# |1000|999|7  |101112|101112 jkl 131415                        |2      |101112 jkl 131415      |
# |1000|999|8  |jkl   |101112 jkl 131415                        |2      |101112 jkl 131415      |
# |1000|999|9  |131415|101112 jkl 131415                        |2      |101112 jkl 131415      |
# |1001|999|1  |aaa   |aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff                  |1      |aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff|
# |1001|999|2  |bbb   |aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff                  |1      |aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff|
# |1001|999|3  |ccc   |aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff                  |1      |aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff|
# |1001|999|4  |ddd   |aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff                  |1      |aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff|
# |1001|999|5  |eee   |aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff                  |1      |aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff|
# |1001|999|6  |fff   |aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff                  |1      |aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff|
# |1002|999|1  |data  |data                                     |1      |data                   |
# |1003|900|1  |stack |stack over flow .com                     |1      |stack over flow .com   |
# |1003|900|2  |over  |stack over flow .com                     |1      |stack over flow .com   |
# |1003|900|3  |flow  |stack over flow .com                     |1      |stack over flow .com   |
# |1003|900|4  |.com  |stack over flow .com                     |1      |stack over flow .com   |
# +----+---+---+------+-----------------------------------------+-------+-----------------------+
```

the `grp_flg` is the grouping column that i created to group sequence of 6 six rows. i used the same as a partition column in `collect_list` window. i added `rowsBetween` because i don't want spark to think i want an cumulative aggregation (default when `orderBy` is provided).